# Comparing columns from different rows in R

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

In R using dplyr I'm struggling to accumulate two columns through a sequence.

What I'd like to do:

Within each `Outlet` I'm trying to calculate the cumulative `DFLSEcr` (cumulative `DFLSEcr` = `cumu_DFLSEcr`) and `count` (`cumu_count`) for each row based on a sequence of `ZHYD` and `NextDown`. Each row has a value for `NextDown` which corresponds to the row which comes before it signified by a matching `ZHYD`. This makes a sequence in which `DFLSEcr` and `count` accumulate. Where `Exutoire == 0` then `cumu_DFLSEcr == 0` and `cumu_count == 0`. If `DFLSEcr == 1 or NA` then don't include it in the sum. I've used `lag()` but I don't think this is correct...

Input:

```
input <- structure(list(ZHYD = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
10L, 8L, 9L, 11L), .Label = c("B020006183", "B020006184", "B020006185", 
"B020006190", "B020006199", "B020006212", "B020006228", "B020006278", 
"B020006285", "B020006290", "B020006325"), class = "factor"), 
    Outlet = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L), .Label = c("BSO0001727", "BSO0001746", "BSO0001756"
    ), class = "factor"), NextDown = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, NA, NA, 4L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("B020006190", 
    "B020006199", "B020006228", "B020006290", "B020006335"), class = "factor"), 
    count = c(15L, 55L, 42L, 19L, 32L, 6L, 19L, 49L, 4L, 82L, 
    5L), DFLSEcr = c(0.07, 0.02, 0.02, 0.05, 0.03, 0.17, 0.05, 
    0.02, 0.25, 0.01, NA), Exutoire = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), .Names = c("ZHYD", "Outlet", "NextDown", "count", "DFLSEcr", 
"Exutoire"))
```

Method tried so far:

```
input %>% 
  group_by(Outlet) %>% 
  select(ZHYD, NextDown, ZHYD, Outlet, Exutoire, count, DFLSEcr) %>%
  mutate(cleanDFLSEcr = replace(DFLSEcr, DFLSEcr == 1, 0), 
         cleanDFLSEcr = replace(DFLSEcr, is.na(DFLSEcr), 0), 
         cumu_DFLSEcr = if_else(Exutoire == 1, 0, cumsum(cleanDFLSEcr)) %>% lag(1, default = 0), 
         cumu_count = if_else(Exutoire == 1, 0, as.numeric(cumsum(count))) %>% lag(1, default = 0)) %>%
  select(-cleanDFLSEcr)
```

Desired output:

```
   ZHYD       Outlet     NextDown   count DFLSEcr Exutoire cumu_count cumu_DFLSEcr
   <fct>      <fct>      <fct>      <int>   <dbl>    <int>      <int>        <dbl>
 1 B020006183 BSO0001727 B020006190    15  0.0700        0         70       0.130 
 2 B020006184 BSO0001727 B020006190    55  0.0200        0         70       0.130 
 3 B020006185 BSO0001727 B020006199    42  0.0200        0         51       0.0800
 4 B020006190 BSO0001727 B020006199    19  0.0500        0         51       0.0800
 5 B020006199 BSO0001727 B020006228    32  0.0300        0         19       0.0500
 6 B020006212 BSO0001727 B020006228     6  0.170         0         19       0.0500
 7 B020006228 BSO0001727 <NA>          19  0.0500        1          0       0.    
 8 B020006290 BSO0001746 <NA>          49  0.0200        1          0       0.    
 9 B020006278 BSO0001746 B020006290     4  0.250         0          1       0.0200
10 B020006285 BSO0001746 B020006290    82  0.0100        0          1       0.0200
11 B020006325 BSO0001756 B020006335     5 NA             0          1       0.0200
```

`cumu_count` and `cumu_DFLSEcr` outputs are the same in some cases because they share the same `NextDown`.

The final row in the sequence shouldn't be included in cumu_count. So for the first row `cumu_count == 19 +32 + 19 = 70`

Edit

Turns out I needed `igraph` as this is a routing problem.

Comment: For the first line, are you sure to desire cumu_count = 15 +55 = 70 ?
Instead of cumu_count == 15+ 19 +32 + 19 = 85 ?

Comment: Good question. The final row in the sequence shouldn't be included in `cumu_count`. So `cumu_count == 19 +32 + 19 = 70`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok your problem is not simple. You have nested data which is a bit complicated to manipulate. 
I give you an answer. There are for sure better ways to do it. But it can give you some ideas.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
father_son_table <-  select(input, actual = ZHYD, father = NextDown)

sequences <- rename(input, actual = ZHYD, father = NextDown) %>% 
  left_join(father_son_table, by = c("father" = "actual"), suffix= c(".1", ".2")) %>% 
  left_join(father_son_table, by = c("father.2" = "actual"), suffix = c(".1", ".3")) %>%  
  tibble::rowid_to_column(var = "sequence_number")



table_order <- sequences  %>% 
  select(-count, -DFLSEcr, -Exutoire, -Outlet) %>% 
  gather(key = height, value = node, -sequence_number) %>%  
  mutate(order = case_when( height == "actual" ~ 0,
                            height =="father.1" ~ 1,
                            height == "father.2" ~ 2,
                            height == "father.3" ~ 3 )) %>%  
  na.omit() %>% 
  select(sequence_number, node, order)

result <- left_join(table_order, input, by = c("node" = "ZHYD")) %>%  
  arrange(sequence_number, order) %>%  
  group_by(sequence_number, Outlet) %>% 
  mutate(cumu_count = sum(count) - count, 
        cumu_DFLSE_cr = sum(DFLSEcr)- DFLSEcr) %>% 
  filter(order == 0)
```

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks Flo.P I appreciate the effort as it is a rather tricky dataset.